# Gaussian Process eating up my memory

Tags: scikit-learn

I have skicit-learn 0.13.1 installed on Ubuntu 12.04. Running the following code is eating up my memory, i.e. I can watch with *top* how memory is growing in each iteration and I get a segmentation fault after approx. 160 iterations (limiting available memory with 'ulimit -Sv 4000000' to approx. 4GB).

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process
import numpy as np


x = np.random.normal(size=(600, 60))            
y = np.random.normal(size=600)

for s in range(100000):

    print 'step %s' % s

    test = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(
            theta0= 1e-2,
            thetaL= 1e-4,
            thetaU= 1e-1,
            nugget= 0.01,
            storage_mode='light').fit(x, y)
```

So am I missing here something?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a serious memory leak. Please report it on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues .